# Why would a production process in an industry know its (population) standard deviation?

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation

I can understand why the mean is known. I can understand that in some cases based on historical data, you have a rough idea about the variance/ standard deviation. But inherently when the real world Statistics problems are divided between the scenarios of sigma-known and sigma-unknown, just wondering why would a new production process in a typical industrial setup, or any other operation for that matter, know what the expected standard deviation is? Any practical examples?

Comment: *"expected standard deviation"*, this term 'expected' implies that the standard deviation is a variable. Possibly this is meant in a Bayesian prior distribution and the true stamdard deviation is fixed? If not did you mean to refer to a process that is not stationary and has a variable standard deviation?

Comment: Also the title sounds weird. The 'production process' doesn't 'know' anything. Is that a grammatical error or did you mean this question to be some philosophical question, like how does an electron in a double slit experiment know which slit it passed through?

Comment: agreed that the question is rather weird, but basically no businessman would allow something to go into production without knowing the typical variation. that's just part of the manufacturing process.

Comment: @seanv507 was your comment directed to me?  In that case, what does the 'but' mean? Are you implying that I have been stating the opposite?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will be more careful with the correctness of the wording of the questions.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus no my comment was mainly directed at OP. (agreeing with you on the weird question)

Answer (score 2):

> why would a new production process in a typical industrial setup, or any other operation for that matter, know what the expected standard deviation is?

Based on estimation. Either by means of experimental tests with the new setup or calculations based on prior knowledge.

Example: Say we have a production line to make medicine pills. The line is composed of different machines (e.g. a machine for dosing, a machine for blending, and a machine for pressing the pills), each with known variations based on prior knowledge. In such a case we can compute what the variations in the final product would be.

Sometimes the estimates based on prior knowledge can also be indirect and can be like an educated guess. For example, when we measure some length visually with a measuring tape (and assume the tape is precise and our vision is the limiting factor), and we make estimates of the size based on an extra decimal, then we can use some fraction of the size between the lines on the measuring tape as the error. This could be like 1/4-th, it should be possible to visually estimate the length with an extra decimal in between the lines of the measuring tape with a precision that is at least 1/4-th.

Comment: I was thinking about Chebyshev's inequality. It is more useful when I know the mean, the variance, but not the distribution.
If my knowledge of variance is because of knowing the past data (or distribution), then I can simply observe or calculate what percentage of data points lie inside/outside k standard deviations, and I don't need to rely on Chebyshev's inequality that only provides lower/upper bounds.
So for Chebyshev's inequality to be truly useful, what are the situations wherein I know the variance but not the distribution.
The measuring tape example was great, by the way. Thanks.

Comment: if the original question was really about chebyshev's inequality, then I would suggest closing and asking about that directly. IMO Chebyshev is used to prove theorems in mathematics rather than in practical applications.

Comment: @PuneUnited I do not get your comments about why you are thinking of the Chebyshev's inequality. A key point might be your sentence *“what are the situations wherein I know the variance but not the distribution.”* and you seem to wonder about the *practical* use of Chebyshev's inequality.